# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus without continuity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, solution-verification

Let be $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ a function which is continuous at point $x_0$.

Then the (first part) of the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus* states that the function
$F(x)=\int\limits_a^xf(t)dt$ is differentiable at $x_0$ where $F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$.

---

I wonder if it is sufficient to assume that the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ exists to make the above statement true?

The crucial steps uses continuity to squeeze $\frac{F(x)-F(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\frac{\int\limits_x^{x_0}f(t)dt}{x-x_0}$ between

$$
M:=\sup\{f(y)\mid y\in[x,x_0]\}\\
m:=\inf\{f(y)\mid y\in[x,x_0]\}, \text{ such that}\\
m\leq\frac{\int\limits_x^{x_0}f(t)dt}{x-x_0}\leq M.
$$

But in my opinion it doesn't matter if $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)=c\neq f(x_0)$. So if someone asks you if $F(x)$ is only differentiable at $x_0$ if $f(x)$ is continuous at point $x_0$, then the answer would be no.

Is this right?

Comment: Of course you can change the value of $f$ at $x_0$ without affecting $F$. But $F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$ will no longer hold.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to x^+_0} f(x)$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to x^-_0} f(x)$ *can* be different from $f(x_0)$, but $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ can't (because $x$ can be equal to $x_0$ infinitely often in the limiting process).

Comment: You should make precise what you want to know. I think it is this: Is it possible that $F$ differentiable at $x_0$ if $f$ is **not** continuous at $x_0$?

Comment: Consider $F(x)=x^2\,\cos\frac1x$ for $x\neq0$ and $F(0)=0$. The derivative $f(x)$ exists everywhere, is not continuous at  $x=0$, but continuous everywhere else (i.e. almost everywhere) and bounded, thus Riemann integrable.